# Why Windows Defender SmartScreen does not show publisher name of a signed executable?

Tags: windows-10, security, certificate, windows-defender, code-signing

I have purchased a Standard Code Signing certificate from Digicert and I do not understand why my executable, although signed with a certificate from a trusted CA is displayed as **Unknown Publisher** by Windows Defender SmartScreen.

[image: Screenshot of file properties showing that although signed, executable does not show Publisher name on Windows Defender SmartScreen]

If I disable "Check applications and files" in "Control applications and browser" of the "Windows Defender Security Center" of Windows 10, my editor name appears correctly in the "Open File - Warning security"

[image: **Open File - Warning security** window shows correct publisher name]

So, I'd really like to understand why the SmartScreen filter in Windows Defender still says **Unknown Publisher**.

I understand that the SmartScreen filter is based on a reputation system and I do not question the actual display of the warning message (as my Code Signing certificate is not an EV one) but the fact that the name of the publisher is indicated as **Unknown Publisher**, whereas a valid signature is present.

Any idea about that? I am code signing wrongly the executable?

Comment: Your certificate meets all requirements for Microsoft code signing, correct?

Comment: Yes, sure, it meets requirements ;)

Comment: Did you find the cause of this? Same issue here. It actually worked for a few days right after signing. Then at some point SmartScreen decided to display "Unknown Publisher", while a UAC prompt right after clicking "Run Anyway" actually shows it as "Verified publisher: XYZ"...

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find the cause of this :( Tried contacting Microsoft through Uservoice, MSDN forums, Technet forums, twitter. No one provide me assistance and my certificate authority neither (Digicert). Still unsolved on my side :(

Comment: @JimmiTh See this related thread on technet https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/440e6b32-1f94-46b0-8185-6f41717b966b/why-windows-defender-smartscreen-does-not-show-publisher-name-of-a-signed-executable-?forum=win10itprosecurity#cd6d7256-6313-422a-9954-22edd0c1c5b9 and on MSDN https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/9292ce79-614c-44bb-bd4e-2dc57a4dd7aa/why-windows-defender-smartscreen-does-not-show-publisher-name-of-a-signed-executable?forum=windowscompatibility#1be57dc5-5151-42c7-a6f9-dda1de7ea6da

Comment: Same problem here. Digicert support said "Alright, I'll get this added to a possible bug, if we hear more about it we'll try reaching out to Microsoft and seeing what changed."

Comment: Thanks @Peter for letting us know. That's really a shame. Theses certs are not cheap and nobody can help us in any way :(

Comment: A [recent blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mmpc/2017/12/11/detonating-a-bad-rabbit-windows-defender-antivirus-and-layered-machine-learning-defenses/) suggests contacting the Defender team via [Microsoft community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect), Twitter @WDSecurity or [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/MsftWDSI/).

Comment: Users experiencing same issue should click on "I have the same question" on this thread https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_defender-protect_scanning-windows_10/regression-windows-defender-smartscreen-now/ee0313e5-0429-45bf-bdab-fd6acdc65474