# "Unknown Publisher" warning when installing a cumulative update on Windows 11 Pro

Tags: windows, certificate, updates, uac

I'm installing the latest cumulative update (2023-11) on Windows 11 Pro and I get the "Unknown Publisher" warning from the UAC. Manually installing the Microsoft Corporation certificate into the Trusted Publishers store did not help.

Could anyone please explain why Microsoft Corporation is an unknown publisher on Windows?

This is a part of a clean offline install of Windows.The update in question was downloaded directly from the [Windows Update Catalog](https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx). When I ran the same update on Windows 10 (just to test), it recognized the publisher correctly.

Technical details:

```
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 23H2
Installed on    ‎11/‎22/‎2023
OS build    22631.2428
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22674.1000.0
```

The update is [KB5032192](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/november-14-2023-kb5032192-os-build-22000-2600-363918ef-c9a4-4f59-957d-4fda57252902). Certificate details:

```
Issued to: Microsoft Corporation
Issued by: Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010
Valid from 2/16/2023 to 1/31/2024
```

The iso file was downloaded directly from Microsoft and burnt on a USB drive using Rufus utility. Some modifications were made by Rufus: it created a local account on my behalf and skipped the privacy screen during the installation. Other than that, no components were added or removed.

The following certificates are in the Trusted Root CA store both for the user account and for local computer:

```
Microsoft Authenticode(tm) Root
Microsoft ECC Product Root Certificate Authority 2018
Microsoft ECC TS Root Certificate Authority 2018
Microsoft Identity Verification Root Certificate Authority 2020
Microsoft Root Authority
Microsoft Root Certificate Authority
Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010
Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2011
Microsoft Time Stamp Root Certificate Authority 2014
```

The only application I have installed before applying the update was Windows Firewall Control. It has never caused any problems in the past.

I've just installed Windows 11 on a VirtualBox VM using the same USB drive, and there's no UAC prompt at all when I run the update installer. It does say, however, that the update (kb5032192) is not applicable to my system, while an older one (kb5031455) is. Weird.

After changing the UAC settings on the VM, I get the UAC prompt when installing the update. Now I'm really confused, because the publisher info (as seen by UAC) looks like this:

- Windows 10 says "Microsoft Corporation" (this seems to be the correct one)
- Windows 11 says "Unknown Publisher"
- Windows 11 on a VM says "Microsoft Windows"

[Certificate info for kb5032192](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DotqY.png)

[Similar question, unanswered since 2017](https://superuser.com/questions/1259119/why-windows-defender-smartscreen-does-not-show-publisher-name-of-a-signed-execut)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149884/discussion-on-question-by-d4xed-unknown-publisher-warning-when-installing-a-cu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.